# PHP 7.1 doctrine Migration xxx failed during Pre-Checks. Error Provided type "?Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaConfig" is invalid: must conform

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony, php-7, dbal

I just upgraded to PHP7.1 using symfony3. When I run a migration using

`./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction`

The issue started when I updated all my packages from PHP 7.0 to 7.1

```
Migrating up to 20160901184952 from 20160511181557
Migration 20160518155844 failed during Pre-Checks. Error Provided type "?Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaConfig" is invalid: must conform "/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*(\\[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)*$/"


  [Zend\Code\Generator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  Provided type "?Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaConfig" is invalid: must conform "/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*(\\[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-z

▽
  A-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)*$/"
```

Comment: You can find my composer.json [here](https://gist.github.com/sameg14/12e9e02917e0e1cfc0e12c3b4bfe165f)

Comment: What is your migration request and how your entity look like ?

Comment: I actually figured this out. As you can see my composer.json references `/var/vendor`. This code runs in the background using [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) which specified `/var/www/app/vendor` as the location of the autoloader. So please ensure that your autoload.php is referenced correctly and consistently.

Comment: I have exactly the same kind of error with "Provided type "?array" is invalid: must conform"… just by trying to clear the cache or launch any command in SF3. My PHP7.1 version is PHP 7.1.0RC2 built: Sep 17 2016…
Downgrading to php7.0 sounds good for the moment